# Double dimension array, attribute value but can't read from it later

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm passing values beteween childs and need to store some values to later use.

the definitions and use in functions

```
char fouts[MAX_SIZE][10];
```

the function where i give the array the values:

```
void connect(char *nodo, char *out[], int nouts) {
(...)
for(i=0;i<nouts;i++) {
                fouts[fnum][i] = out[i];
}
(...)
```

and the function where i'm trying to use them:

```
void disconnect(char *nodo, char *remover){
char *outs[10];
nouts = fnouts[getfnum];
int m =0;
    for(i=0;i<nouts;i++) {
            if(strcmp(fouts[getfnum][i],nodo) != 0) { outs[m] = fouts[getfnum][i];  m++ ; }
}
```

no matter what i did to try to fixm everytime it tries to execute this last for, it gives a segmentation fault.

have tried somethings (read fouts[getfnum][0] for example directly and gives a segmentaton fault, but fouts[getfnum] gives "trash")
check the value after it been atributed  fouts[fnum][i] = out[i]; here and it checks out, so i guess that part is ok).

don't know if its something obvious or not, but any help?

Comment: You pass nouts to connect but not to disconnect.How does disconnect get nouts?

Comment: Don't know if its causing a problem, but `char *outs[10]` is a pointer to an array with 10 elements, but you never allocate the pointer before writing to it? As stated, don't know if this should cause any problems.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson forgot to include here, but i get the value. edited and added that

Comment: @LudvigRydahl i guess it not there the problem, because if for example, when i try to do a printf("%s",fouts[getfnum][0]); i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: `fouts[fnum][i]` is a `char` but you assign it with `out[i]` which is `char*`

Comment: Using type `char` for the array index, are you positive the index never exceeds `127`? (if it does, your index may be interpreted as a negative value -- by definition, outside the bounds of your array)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oh, yes, it passes 127. so that is the problem.

any sugestion on how to fix this?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i did put the problem, things that i've tried and what i was expecting...

Comment: @JoséMoreira try the following: create a new C project, copy the code from your *question* (nothing from your local disk) into the project and compile it. If it's compilable, runnable and produces the same error as you describe, then it is a complete and verifyable example of your problem, otherwise you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `char` and `char*`.

```
fouts[fnum][i] is a char
```

and

```
out[i] is a char pointer
```

So in this line

```
fouts[fnum][i] = out[i];
```

you assign a `char pointer` to a `char` which is illegal.

And in this line

```
if(strcmp(fouts[getfnum][i],nodo) != 0)
```

you pass a `char` (i.e. `fouts[getfnum][i]`) to `strcmp`.

That is not legal as `strcmp` expects a `char*`

From the posted code, it is hard to tell how to fix the problems. Maybe you just need:

```
char* fouts[MAX_SIZE][10];
```

Comment: it gives a warning, but even if i only did an
printf of the fouts[getfnum][i] still getting an segmentation fault.

Comment: @JoséMoreira - How do you print it?

Comment: in the for loop that i atributed the values i've printed the value of the array fouts[getfnum][i] and it printed right.

Meanwhile i changed my code and not use this option, couldn't manage to get it to work.